# How can i show menu icon and not back arrow on navbar moving from page 1 to page 2 - IONIC

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

When i open my app, the 1st page which appears is `Login.html` , after filling the form, it navigates to `dashboard.html`

**Problem:**  When it goes to `Dashboard.html` , it shows back arrow on the top left and not the menu icon. **I want it to show menu icon here and not the back arrow**

This is the code i am using for navigation in `login.ts`:

```
if(data[0].USR==1)
       {
         this.navCtrl.push(DashboardPage);

       }
```

Image of `dashboard.html`, please notice the arrow on left side

[image]

I have to click this arrow > go back to login > then from menu icon, i open menu and select dashboard page, then i see menu icon on dashboard.. why so  ?

I have also created a video , sharing its youtube link - http://youtu.be/1eA5KXJkSDE?hd=1

Comment: were you able to solve this @user2828442?

Answer (score 1):

It's default of Ionic when you navigate using `push`

If you wanna show menu toggle icon, you should use `setRoot`

Example:

```
onClickNavigate() {
  console.log("onNavigate");

 this.navCtrl.setRoot("PageTwo")
}
```

in "PageTwo" html, you need to add toggle button on the header too

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <button ion-button menuToggle>
          <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
        </button>
        <ion-title>page-two</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to set the `DashboardPage` as *a root page*, so instead of the `push` method, use `setRoot`:

```
if(data[0].USR == 1) {
  this.navCtrl.setRoot(DashboardPage);
}
```